# how to get file url from kaltura by entryid

Tags: java, kaltura

I have to get video url uploaded on kaltura by entryId. I have seen kaltura api, but  didn't get proper solution for that.I got something in php code:

```
 $ks = $client->session->start($secret, $userId, KalturaSessionType::ADMIN, $partnerId, 86400, 'disableentitlement');
$client->setKs($ks);

$client->startMultiRequest();
$entryId = '1_u7aj9kasw'; //replace this with your entry Id
$client->flavorAsset->getwebplayablebyentryid($entryId);
$req1ResultFlavorId = '{1:result:0:id}'; //get the first flavor from the result of getwebplayablebyentryid
$client->flavorAsset->geturl($req1ResultFlavorId); //this action will return a valid download URL
$multiRequestResults = $client->doMultiRequest();
$downloadUrl = $multiRequestResults[1];
echo 'The entry download URL is: '.$downloadUrl;
```

but i have to do it with java ,what i have tried like :

```
KalturaConfiguration config = new KalturaConfiguration();
        config.setEndpoint(envConfiguration.getKalturaUrl());
        KalturaClient client = new KalturaClient(config);
        String ks = client.generateSession(envConfiguration.getKalturaSecretKey(), "TestUploader",
                KalturaSessionType.ADMIN, 101);
        client.setKs(ks);
        client.startMultiRequest();
        String url = client.getFlavorAssetService().getUrl("entryid");
        log.debug("url is::::::"+ url);
```

but i am getting url null .Please help.
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You have started a multi request but not run it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "fix my codez" that shows no effort.